# Problem with mmap/munmap - getting a bus error after the 783rd iteration?

Tags: c, linux, memory-management

Okay, here's the setup: I work in HPC, and we're preparing for the need to scale up to tens of thousands of nodes. To deal with this, I've implemented a local process that caches information on each node to reduce the amount of network traffic. It then exposes this information via shared-memory. The basic logic is that there is one well-known shared memory block that contains the names of the currently cached tables. When an update occurs, the cache tool creates a new shared memory table, fills it, then updates the well-known block with the name of the new table.

The code appears to be working find (valgrind says no memory leaks, for example) but when I deliberately stress test it, the first 783 updates work perfectly fine - but on the 784th, I get a SIGBUS error when I attempt to write to the mapped memory.

If the problem is too many open files (because I'm leaking file descriptors) I'd expect shm_open() to fail. If the problem was that I was leaking mapped memory, I'd expect mmap() to fail or valgrind to report leaks.

Here's the code fragment. Can anyone offer a suggestion?

```
int
initialize_paths(writer_t *w, unsigned max_paths)
{
int err = 0;
reader_t *r = &(w->unpublished);

close_table(r,PATH_TABLE);

w->max_paths = max_paths;

err = open_table(r, PATH_TABLE, O_RDWR | O_CREAT, max_paths, 0);

return err;
}

static void
close_table(reader_t *r, int table)
{
    if (r->path_table && r->path_table != MAP_FAILED) {
       munmap(r->path_table,r->path_table->size);
       r->path_table=NULL;
    }
    if (r->path_fd>0) { close(r->path_fd); r->path_fd=0; }
}


static int
open_table(op_ppath_reader_t *r, int table, int rw, unsigned c, unsigned c2)
{
// Code omitted for clarity
if (rw & O_CREAT) {
    prot = PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE;
} else {
    // Note that this overrides the sizes set above.
    // We will get the real sizes from the header.
    prot = PROT_READ;
    size1 = sizeof(op_ppath_header_t);
    size2 = 0;
}

fd = shm_open(name, rw, 0644);
if (fd < 0) {
    _DBG_ERROR("Failed to open %s\n",name);
    goto error;
}

if (rw & O_CREAT) {
    /* Create the file at the specified size. */
    if (ftruncate(fd, size1 + size2)) {
        _DBG_ERROR("Unable to size %s\n",name);
        goto error;
    }
}

h = (op_ppath_header_t*)mmap(0, size1 + size2, prot, MAP_SHARED, fd, 0);
if (h == MAP_FAILED) {
    _DBG_ERROR("Unable to map %s\n",name);
    goto error;
}

if (rw & O_CREAT) {
    /*
     * clear the table & set the maximum lengths.
     */
    memset((char*)h,0,size1+size2);  -- SIGBUS OCCURS HERE
    h->s1 = size1;
    h->s2 = size2;
} else {
// more code omitted for clarity.
}
```

**UPDATE:**

Here's some sample debugging output of a failure:

```
NOTICE: Pass 783: Inserting records.
NOTICE: Creating the path table.
TRC: initialize_paths[
TRC: close_table[
TRC: close_table]
TRC: open_table[
DBG: h=0x0x2a956b2000, size1=2621536, size2=0
```

Here's the same output from the previous iteration:

```
NOTICE: Pass 782: Inserting records.
NOTICE: Creating the path table.
TRC: initialize_paths[
TRC: close_table[
TRC: close_table]
TRC: open_ppath_table[
DBG: h=0x0x2a956b2000, size1=2621536, size2=0
TRC: open_ppath_table]
TRC: op_ppath_initialize_paths]
```

Note that the pointer address is valid, and so is the size.

GDB reports the crash this way:

```
Program received signal SIGBUS, Bus error.
[Switching to Thread 182895447776 (LWP 5328)]
0x00000034a9371d20 in memset () from /lib64/tls/libc.so.6
(gdb) where
#0  0x00000034a9371d20 in memset () from /lib64/tls/libc.so.6
#1  0x0000002a955949d0 in open_table (r=0x7fbffff188, table=1, rw=66,
c=32768, c2=0) at ofedplus_path_private.c:294
#2  0x0000002a95595280 in initialize_paths (w=0x7fbffff130,
    max_paths=32768) at path_private.c:567
#3  0x0000000000402050 in server (fname=0x7fbffff270 "gidtable", n=10000)
    at opp_cache_test.c:202
#4  0x0000000000403086 in main (argc=6, argv=0x7fbffff568)
    at opp_cache_test.c:542
```

(gdb)

Removing the memset still causes a SIGBUS when h->size1 is set on the following line - and size1 is the first 4 bytes of the mapped area.

Comment: what are the values of size1 and size2 for the O_CREAT case?

Comment: Could you stress test this code using gdb (e.g. in batch mode), place a breakpoint before the memset call to print the value of *h* and then continue?    

If it run's fine within gdb it's more then possibly a memory leak / out-of-buffer write.

Comment: size1 is about 256k in this case. For the stress test it is always the same size.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's possible that the SIGBUS is caused by to many references to your SHM object.
Looking at your code above you use **shm_open()**, **mmap()**, **munmap()** but
you're missing **shm_unlink()**.

As the manpage for ***shm_open** / **shm_close** states these objects are reference counted.

> The operation of **shm_unlink** is analogous to **unlink**(2): it removes a shared memory object
>   name, and, once all processes have unmapped the object, deallocates  and  destroys  the
>   contents of the associated memory region.
>   After a successful **shm_unlink**, attempts to **shm_open** an object with the same
>   name will fail (unless **O_CREAT** was specified, in which case a new, distinct object is created).

Maybe this information will help solving your problem.

Comment: I already knew about shm_unlink() and I was using it in a different context, but your suggestion made me go back through the code and double-check - and I discovered that, indeed, old data was never getting unlinked. I'm guessing that I was effectively exhausting the number of shared memory regions that Linux can have at one time.